# How do I find the formula of the compound given the ratio of its constituents by weight?

Tags: stoichiometry

Problem : An organic compound containing carbon, nitrogen and oxygen will have a weight ratio $9:1:3$. The molecular weight of the compound is $108$. What is the formula of the compound?

I thought of calculating the empirical formula, but percentages are given for that, and not weight.

Answer (score 1):

It's an algebra problem.

108 = 9x + 1x + 3x

Solve for x.

Weight of carbon per molecule = 9x
Weight of nitrogen per molecule = 1x
Weight of oxygen per molecule = 3x

Then convert from weights to numbers (I assume you know how to do that  :)  ).

Note that the result is rather nonsensical, as it gives you fractional atoms.

Comment: The answer is given as $C_6H_8N_2$.